# sandbox paypal integration

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate the paypal sandbox using the [paypal developer link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/quick-start/).

I have searched many examples. But the sandbox paypal(https://www.sandbox.paypal.com) is totally different from https://paypal.com.

In sandbox has the Merchant id, user id, password and signature.

how to i find out the "demo_sandbox_client_id"?

Is Merchant ID is same as client id?

Answer (score 0):

To get the client_ID, you need to make an app in [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com). Remember that you need a sandbox business account to be able to make an app, and for that, you can log in to the developer website with any personal or business paypal account. You then need to follow the link there to connect your sandbox business account to your developer account (by logging in with your sandbox credentials in paypal.com).

Comment: so, have to create app through https://www.paypal.com/ to got client id?

It goes to following link(https://www.paypal.com/signin) , while i try to login through developer account(for create app).

I have sandbox business account.
but my sandbox account couldn't logged in https://www.paypal.com/signin. 
It's login with https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/signin

Comment: On https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/ page you should see a line saying "To link your sandbox account to your developer account, log in with PayPal and provide your sandbox account credentials." This will redirect you to sandbox.paypal.com and you can link your sandbox account with the developer account

Comment: but my account couldn't login with https://www.paypal.com/signin?country.x=US&locale.x=en_US

Comment: You cannot (and should not be able to) login to paypal.com using sandbox accounts, but you can login to developer.paypal.com using __any__ paypal account, and then login to sandbox.paypal.com using any business account made through the developer site. I hope this helps! The model is pretty convoluted and the documentation is crappy though...

Comment: so, have to use any paypal account and also sanbox paypal business account? right?

Comment: Right. and to make sure linking them is not a problem make the sandbox business account inside a logged-in session on developer.paypal.com

Comment: I got an issue from sandbox paypal integration that was "We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please go back to the merchant and try using a different payment method".
I have used this link(https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/quick-start/) for integration.

Comment: The error message doesn't tell much to me how to diagnose it, but I would start with these two: 1- check that the status of the business account in developer.paypal is "complete" and not "error". 2- check the settings like "Manage PayPal checkout settings" on sandbox.paypal

Comment: I've used just the HTML and JavaScript code and slightly changed the client id using this link(developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/quick-start).
The user account is logged in but it couldn't proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications
2. Sign in using your **email account**.
3. Under Dashboard > My apps and credentials > **REST API apps**
   [image]
4. Create an app (if not yet existing)
5. Click the app, then use the **clientID** as the sandbox ID
6. To know which account to use to pay, go to right menu > SANDBOX > Accounts
7. Copy the email with the **buyer** keyword. Change the password.
8. To check if the sandboxId works, use this site (supply the **sandbox key** with the clientId)
   https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/checkout